# Install web server on EC2 instance to host code by given Bastion IP and instance ID

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was asked to build object share app project on AWS, and I was given the EC2 Bastion IP and EC2 Instance ID and SSH key pem file, they asked to install web server on EC2 instance, so what can I do with the IP and ID they gave to me?
Don't know where to start. Thanks

Comment: Who are "they"? Is this a training exercise, or something in a real job? Isn't there somebody you can ask?

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that based on the configuration you've been provided the following is being expected of you.

SSH to the bastion host using the SSH pem you've provided. You will need to know the OS of the bastion host to know which username to connect to it as (Amazon Linux uses `ec2-user`, Ubuntu is `ubuntu` etc).

From this bastion host you can then connect to the target instance host, (you will need to map the instance ID to the instance IP, which requires a lookup either via the console, CLI or SDK with valid credentials).

If you don't have access to some of this information you will need to ask for it to be provided to you.

Comment: Thanks, so I have successfully SSH into the instance by using Putty, Bastion IP and pem. file. But I don't know how to map the ID to IP, cause I can not access the console.  Thanks.

Comment: This can only be accessed through the console programmatically unfortunately as it is an ID that resides within AWS. Unless you have access to either of these ways you'll need to ask someone to provide you :(

Answer (score 1):

It seems the bastion has Access to get the **private IP address of instances** and the **web server in private subnet** so use AWS-cli or you can try using your own credential to get the IP using below command.

- SSH to bastion Server and run below command by passing `INSTANCE_ID`

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids ${INSTANCE_ID} --query Reservations[].Instances[].NetworkInterfaces[].PrivateIpAddress
```

- This will return the private IP address of the Ec2 instance, then create  `ssh config` file and do `ssh tunnel` from your local system.

`vi ~/.ss/config`

Now add the following

```
host bastion
   HostName 52.X.X.X
   User BASTION_USER
   identityFile ~/.ssh/bastionkey.pem

Host webserver
   hostname 10.x.x.x
   user WEB_USER
   ProxyCommand ssh bastion -W %h:%p
```

Now you are good to connect with ec2

```
ssh webserver
```

Comment: thanks, I was provided with credentials. The requirement is to install web server on ec2 instance host my code and write a photo upload webpage , user can upload jpeg photo to S3. I choose JAVA and Eclipse as my frame, but don't where to start.

Comment: Awesome so I hope your user will also able to find the IP of instance using aws-cli, connect to ec2 instance place your code on ec2 machine then upload file from ec2 to s3